# theo use of undeclared type 'Client' swift

Tags: swift, xcode, neo4j

I installed cocoa pods and set the target for my app to Theo
To test it, I went to playground and typed:

```
let theo: Client = Client(baseURL: "hostname.com")
```

I get the following error

> use of undeclared type 'Client'

Any help on how I may initiate the package. I'm new to using xcode and theo.

Comment: You forgot to `import Theo`

Comment: https://neo4j.com/blog/theo-3-0-swift-framework-neo4j/